# Synchronization of many databases?

Tags: php, database, laravel, synchronization

I have a web application using a postgress database. Several web-based accounting programs with their own databases are integrated with the web application. It is necessary to implement synchronization of all databases. In other words, if something was changed in one database, then all other databases should synchronize the data.

I have never done this before and would like to know what solutions or methods exist for this?

Synchronization should occur using web api.

Comment: Something like this might help - https://medium.com/studocu-techblog/how-to-deal-with-database-master-slave-replication-delay-in-laravel-dab872a09a3f

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `DB::listen()` to get all your queries and then replicate each insert, update or delete query.

```php
# app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        // Only listens to default connection, no need to worry on it firing on each replication
        DB::listen(function ($query) {
            if(Str::startsWith($query->sql, ['insert', 'update', 'delete'])) {
                DB::connection('connection2')->statement($query->sql, $query->bindings);
                DB::connection('connection3')->statement($query->sql, $query->bindings);
                DB::connection('connection4')->statement($query->sql, $query->bindings);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty neat solution

Comment: Thanks. That said, I do not know if it's a good practice for this scenario. It's just how I'd approach the problem initially.